# Error 'struct android::MediaRecorderBase' has no member named 'pause'

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, compiling

I'm trying to build Ubuntu phone on Nexus 4, and am stuck with the following error. Could you please help me find out what I missed or did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
ubuntu/libhybris/compat/media/media_recorder_client.cpp: In member function 'virtual android::status_t android::MediaRecorderClient::pause()':
ubuntu/libhybris/compat/media/media_recorder_client.cpp:265:22: error: 'struct android::MediaRecorderBase' has no member named 'pause'
ubuntu/libhybris/compat/media/media_recorder_client.cpp:267:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [/home/young/phablet/out/target/product/mako/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libmedia_compat_layer_intermediates/media_recorder_client.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AudioSource.cpp: In constructor 'android::AudioSource::AudioSource(audio_source_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)':
frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AudioSource.cpp:76:42: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What compiler version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get past this in the compilation, I introduced a bug. Changing

```
return recorder->pause();
```

to

```
return NO_INIT;
```

Allows compilation to continue, but that is by no means a sustainable "fix".